# MongoDB C# OfType() Indexing behavior

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-indexes

Suppose I have this query over a Collection:

```
var dbMarkers = Features.AsQueryable<DBFeature>()
                        .OfType<DBPointFeature>()
                        .Where(f => f.parentFeatureSetId = parentFeatureSetId );
```

And the features are indexed (sparse) by:

```
{ "parentFeatureSetId": 1 }
```

As I understand, the C# driver uses the Type information **DBFeature** and **DBPointFeature** as an additional filter when building the query.

I would like to know if the Index is applied BEFORE the type Query, so it will be limited to the Index subset.

If not, it would be first fetching all the items of a particular type (which is a set much bigger than the idexed set), and the index would be almost pointless.

What is the behavior of MongoDB in this case?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only `parentFeatureSetId` is indexed, then that will be the index `MongoDB` uses. It will first find the documents with the specified `parentFeatureSetId` and then scan them for the ones with the right type.

You *could* however have the type discriminator field (`_t`) indexed as well, which may improve performance. In this case mongo will [intersect](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/) both indexes and scan only the subset of items that have **both** the right type and `parentFeatureSetId`

---

**Important note:** The C# driver will not use `DBFeature` while building the query, it will only use `DBPointFeature` which you noted the documents must be specifically. The generic `AsQueryable` is only there to ease the usage.